# Is there a way to set the input option "wrap" as the default behavior for an entier project?

Tags: input, 4gl, genero

When tabbing through an input form, the default behaviour is to exit the input after the last field, instead of going back to the first field. By using `OPTIONS INPUT WRAP` in the before input block, this can be avoided.

However, this has to be done for each input individually. Is there a way to set this as the default behaviour for an entire project(4pw)?

I am currently using Genero Studio 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have to be called for each INPUT individually.  It is a runtime option and so can be set once at the beginning and forgotten.  Most developers will have a library function they call near the start of each of their applications and place it in there.